# Primefaces Datatable Conditional (Multi)Coloring Rows

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I want to color some datatable rows based on this example: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/rowColor.xhtml.

How can I put an if-elseIf block inside the rowStyleClass so I can set more than one color per condition?

**Illustrative** example:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{myController.items}" var="item"
             rowStyleClass="#{item.realizado le 29 ? 'yes' : null}"
             rowStyleClass="#{item.status.id gt 1 ? 'unavailable' : null}"
</p:dataTable>
```

The idea is to 'join' the conditions in rowStyleClass above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by `more than one color per condition`?

Comment: SRy, sorry, but I think my question is very clear enough. See the correct answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will work:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{myController.items}" var="item"
             rowStyleClass="#{item.realizado le 29 ? 'yes' : null} #{item.status.id gt 1 ? 'unavailable' : null}"
</p:dataTable>
```